# I can´t open jupyter notebook from a new enviroment with anaconda prmpt. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, conda, virtual-environment

After installing jupyter notebook in both enviroments, nb_conda_kernels, ipykernel, and all the libraries I'll need, this is what I´ve written in anaconda prompt (the enviroment I´ve crated is called *hands_on_ml*):

```
(base)$ conda activate hands_on_ml
(hands_on_ml)$ jupyter notebook
```

And I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\hands_on_ml\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6, in <module>
    from notebook.notebookapp import main
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\hands_on_ml\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 75, in <module>
    from .base.handlers import Template404, RedirectWithParams
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\hands_on_ml\lib\site-packages\notebook\base\handlers.py", line 35, in <module>
    from notebook.utils import is_hidden, url_path_join, url_is_absolute, url_escape, urldecode_unix_socket_path
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\hands_on_ml\lib\site-packages\notebook\utils.py", line 8, in <module>
    import ctypes
  File "C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\hands_on_ml\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _ctypes: No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado.
```

I´ve also tried to open jupyter notebook with *(base)$* to create a new *.ipynb* by selecting *Python [conda env: hands_on_ml]* but in the prompt the same error appears over and over again and so I can´t connect to kernel.

If someone can help me. I'm not used to use the terminal.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: just to roughly translates the error message for others: `_ctypes: can't find the specified module`

Answer (score 0):

I think so didn't install 'ctypes' package your environment. Try to install this package with conda run one of the following and check it again

```
conda install -c conda-forge pywin32-ctypes
conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf201901 pywin32-ctypes
conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf202003 pywin32-ctypes
```

ref. https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pywin32-ctypes

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I installed one of those and tried to open jupyter notebook, but I get the same error with all of them. I don´t know what could it be.